# Throttling brute force login attacks in Django

Tags: python, django, security, brute-force

Are there generally accepted tactics for protecting Django applications against this kind of attack?

Answer (score 7):

There are many libraries available for it like **Django-axes**, **Django-defender**, **Django-ratelimit**, these libraries mentioned all do the same thing (with a few differences between them). You can choose the one which best suits your needs.

If you are using DRF, then you don't need an additional library (axes, ratelimit, etc.) because DRF already has the throttling functionality build in.

You can check this question :[**How to prevent brute force attack in Django Rest + Using Django Rest Throttling
**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49936101/how-to-prevent-brute-force-attack-in-django-rest-using-django-rest-throttling)

Comment: A note on DRF's throttling from the DRF documentation: 

"The application-level throttling that REST framework provides should not be considered a security measure or protection against brute forcing or denial-of-service attacks. Deliberately malicious actors will always be able to spoof IP origins."

Answer (score 5):

You can:

- Keep track of the failed login attempts and block the attacker after 3 attempts.
- If you don't want to block then you can log it and present a CAPTCHA to make it more difficult in future attempts.
- You can also increase the time between login attempts after eached failed attempt. For example, 10 seconds, 30 seconds, 1 minute, 5 minutes, et cetera. This will spoil the fun pretty quickly for the attacker.
- Of course, choose a secure password as that will keep the attacker guessing.

Answer (score 2):

As this question was asked ~7 years ago, perhaps some more recent information might be helpful.

Implementing [Google reCAPTCHA v3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/) might be better than blindly throttling all traffic. It can tell if someone is just hammering the password and will block them accordingly. If someone looks like a human but is just getting their password wrong, it won't block them as quickly. Google knows more about the www then any one of us, so we might as well leverage that.