# Django login with django-axes

Tags: python, django, django-login

I created a site with django. Users should be able to login. The login-view looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
....
if request.method == 'POST':       
        username = request.POST['username']#get username
        password = request.POST['txtPwd']# and password 
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password) #checking username and pwd
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
```

But with this "solution" i can't handle an brute force attack. So I looked around and found this: 
[Throttling brute force login attacks in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477067/throttling-brute-force-login-attacks-in-django)

The first answer was helpful. I choosed django-axes because django-ratelimit count only the amout of calling a view.

But here is my problem: When i try to login with wrong password it doesn't count the failure. (Only at the /admin-section).

I found no option to "add" my login-view to django-axes.

So here is my question:

How can I configure django-axes to handle the failed logins from my login-view?

**EDIT:**
Here is my settings-file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'axes',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'axes.middleware.FailedLoginMiddleware'
)

...

AXES_LOCK_OUT_AT_FAILURE = False
AXES_USE_USER_AGENT = True
AXES_COOLOFF_TIME = 1
AXES_LOGIN_FAILURE_LIMIT = 50
```

Comment: How did you use django-axes in your project? Give more info about your settings file.

Comment: Ok, I added the settings-file. I dont't really know how to use it(This is the mainproblem). The project-website gives no informations how to use it for other sites.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default `django-axes` used django's login view *(`django.contrib.auth.views.login`). In middleware this view decorate with `watch_login`.

So you can solve your issue in two ways:

- use standard login view. In this way `django-axes` does not require additional setup.
- decorate your's login view with `watch_login` decorator.

For example: `views.py`

```python
from axes.decorators import watch_login
...

@watch_login
def your_custom_login_view(request):
    ...
```

It will then be used like this in class based view as mentioned by @Ali Faizan:

```python
@method_decorator(watch_login, name='dispatch')
class your_custom_login_view():
     ...
```

Comment: Please also note that if your view is class the it will be used like this
`
@method_decorator(watch_login, name='dispatch')
class your_custom_login_view():
`

Answer (score 0):

In newer version you can use `@axes_dispatch` instead of `@watch_login`

```py
from axes.decorators import axes_dispatch

@axes_dispatch
def custom_login_view(request):
   # .....some code......
```