# django-axes with custom user model

Tags: django, django-authentication

I’ve been struggling to include **django-axes** into a project where I’m using a **custom User model**. Finally, I got this almost working. I say “almost” because none errors are shown, but unfortunately django-axes is **not catching failed login attempts**.

In fact, it is showing in the admin that the user got logged (and, therefore, the user is never logout). I think I'm getting exactly the same problem indicated here: [Django-axes not working with custom login view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116107/django-axes-not-working-with-custom-login-view?lq=1)

I’ll show you some parts of my code, so maybe you could shed some light into this issue. 
THANKS IN ADVANCE

**urls.py**

```
from axes.decorators import watch_login
from apps.main.views import userLogin
urlpatterns = patterns(‘',

    url(r'^login/$', watch_login(userLogin), name="login"),
```

**views.py**

```
    from axes.decorators import watch_login

    @watch_login
    def userLogin(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            if 'login_form' in request.POST:
                username = request.POST.get('username', '')
                password = request.POST.get('password', '')
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                if user is not None: # The user exists, credentials OK
                    if user.is_active:
                        login(request, user) # Log the user
                        if not request.POST.get('rememberUser', None): 
                            request.session.set_expiry(3600) 
                    else:
                        return redirect('users_app:disabled_account')
                else:
                    return redirect('users_app:login_failed')
        return redirect('main_app:index')

    def LogOut(request):
        logout(request)
        return redirect('/‘)

    class IncorrectLoginView(TemplateView):
        template_name = 'users/login_failed.html'
```

**base.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASES = (
   'da_tracker.middleware.TrackerMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: Hard to say; I would start with `import pdb ; pdb.set_trace()` somewhere in django-axes to diagnose further

Comment: I've edited the code, including the complete code of the userLogin view

Comment: It looks like django-axes detect as a correct login when the login has failed. Isn't there any other decorator similar to @watch_login but for failed attempts so that I could add it to the login_failed view? Thank you very much

Comment: Can you do IRC? I would suggest asking in #django on the Freenode network. I'm active there on most days.

Comment: It seems no need config in urls.py. Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25781806/851185