# How to prevent brute force attack in Django Rest + Using Django Rest Throttling

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

***Block particular user for some specific time to using Django REST Throttling.***

I have seen [Django REST Throttling](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/).

I don't want to use third-party packages.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found the solution after customized Django REST Throttling,

Its Blocking particular user after 3 login attempts (Block user_id that presents in my application).
Block IP address after 6 login attempts for anonymous user.

**prevent.py**:-

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from collections import Counter

from rest_framework.throttling import SimpleRateThrottle
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserLoginRateThrottle(SimpleRateThrottle):
    scope = 'loginAttempts'

    def get_cache_key(self, request, view):
        user = User.objects.filter(username=request.data.get('username'))
        ident = user[0].pk if user else self.get_ident(request)

        return self.cache_format % {
            'scope': self.scope,
            'ident': ident
        }

    def allow_request(self, request, view):
        """
        Implement the check to see if the request should be throttled.
        On success calls `throttle_success`.
        On failure calls `throttle_failure`.
        """
        if self.rate is None:
            return True

        self.key = self.get_cache_key(request, view)
        if self.key is None:
            return True

        self.history = self.cache.get(self.key, [])
        self.now = self.timer()

        while self.history and self.history[-1] <= self.now - self.duration:
            self.history.pop()

        if len(self.history) >= self.num_requests:
            return self.throttle_failure()

        if len(self.history) >= 3:
            data = Counter(self.history)
            for key, value in data.items():
                if value == 2:
                    return self.throttle_failure()
        return self.throttle_success(request)

    def throttle_success(self, request):
        """
        Inserts the current request's timestamp along with the key
        into the cache.
        """
        user = User.objects.filter(username=request.data.get('username'))
        if user:
            self.history.insert(0, user[0].id)
        self.history.insert(0, self.now)
        self.cache.set(self.key, self.history, self.duration)
        return True
```

**view.py**:-

```
  from .prevent import UserLoginRateThrottle
   ....
   ....
   ....
   class ObtainAuthToken(auth_views.ObtainAuthToken):
       throttle_classes = (UserLoginRateThrottle,)/use this method here your login view

       def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           ....
       ....
```

Add some parameters in setting file

**settings.py**:-

```
# Django-rest-framework
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle',

    ),
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'loginAttempts': '6/hr',
        'user': '1000/min',
    }
}
```