# How to remove user from Django Blocked list (User blocked by Django throttle)?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm using [`Django REST throttling`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/) to block the user after 5 login attempts.

I'm using the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49936101/how-to-prevent-brute-force-attack-in-django-rest-using-django-rest-throttling) to block the user.

> Now I want to add a feature where an admin can reset blocked users,
>   meaning to remove a blocked user from the blocked list.

**How can I remove the user from Django Blocked list?**

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Block User present on Django `caches['default']`.

1)Show all Block Users

```
def show_blocked_users():
    """
    Get all blocked users
    """
    throttle_user_list = []
    caches_list = caches['default']._expire_info
    if caches_list:
        for cache in caches_list:
            cache_key = cache.replace(':1:', '')
            user_attepts = caches['default'].get(cache_key)
            count_attepts = Counter(user_attepts)
            for key, value in count_attepts.items():
                if value == 4:
                    throttle_user_id = cache.replace(':1:throttle_loginAttempts_', '')
                    user = User.objects.filter(id=throttle_user_id)
                    if user:
                        throttle_user_list.append({'key': cache_key,
                                                   'full_name': user[0].first_name + ' ' + user[0].last_name,
                                                   'username': user[0].username,
                                                   })
    return throttle_user_list
```

2) Remove Block User from list:

```
def reset_users(request):
    """
    Remove/Reset Block User from block list
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        key = request.POST.get('key')
        key_exist = caches['default'].get(key)
        if key_exist:
            caches['default'].delete(key)
```